# Only run a function if it is a new session

Tags: init-file, ess

In my `init.el` file, I have a hook to setup my workspace when I open a particular type file. Specifically, when I open an R file (i.e., `*.R`) and ESS-mode starts, a couple of other windows open with `vterm` and `R` in them. My Elisp code looks like this:

```
;; R setup                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
(require 'ess-site)
(add-hook 'ess-mode-hook
          (lambda()
            (set-window-buffer (selected-window)
                               (file-name-nondirectory (car (last command-line-args))))
            (split-window-horizontally)
            (other-window 1)
            (vterm)
            (split-window-vertically)
            (R)
            (other-window 1)
            ))
```

When I open a file, say `emacs myfile.R`, this works as expected. I run into a problem, however, if I open a file once Emacs is already up and running. For example, I run `emacs myfile.R` and then do `C-x C-f myfile2.R` then this causes more windows to open.

**Q:** Is there a way to only run this startup function when there isn't an existing emacs session?

Comment: Curious: are you running R in the vterm buffer, or are you using vterm for other stuff alongside R?

Comment: The idea was to have a `vterm` open for other stuff, like git. But now you mention it, I wonder if my `R` instance is running from `vterm`... Regardless, on my system, this function creates three windows: editor with the file I opened, `vterm`, and `R`.

Comment: Ok. Without some (maybe a lot?) tweaking, R won't be running in `vterm`. I haven't tried `vterm` yet, but it sounds quite interesting. For `git` specifically, [magit](https://magit.vc/) is amazing!

Comment: Ah, I see. (I'm a newb so I'm not really sure what I'm doing). Another person here recommended `vterm` and so far it's great. Thanks for the tip about `magit`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have a solution. I define my setup in a function that is *only* called at startup, like so:

```
;; Define R setup function                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
(defun R_setup()
  "Setup R"
  (set-window-buffer (selected-window)
                     (file-name-nondirectory (car (last command-line-args))))
  (split-window-horizontally)
  (other-window 1)
  (vterm)
  (split-window-vertically)
  (R)
  (other-window 1)
  )

;; Startup hook for R                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook
          (lambda()
            (if (equal (file-name-extension (car (last command-line-args))) "R")
                (R_setup))
          ))
```

This way I only check that it is an R file at startup and if it is then perform my setup. When Emacs is already up and running, no such check is performed, so no setup is performed.